# How do I debug a go app started with heroku local web in vscode

Tags: go, heroku, visual-studio-code

I have a go app deploying on heroku. usually I start with `heroku local web` and attach debugger later by find process id.

how can I start into debug mode?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to start delve in headless mode (`dlv attach --headless ...`) and connect to the server using remote debugging configuration (`remote` mode, `attach` request type). https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#connecting-to-headless-delve-with-target-specified-at-server-start-up ?

Comment: hi, thanks @Hana yes, I was able to do attach to a started process, but in this way I can't debug the very starting point of the app. I can debug handler in this way.

Comment: then use `dlv exec --headless ...`. (I suggested `attach` because you mentioned you wanted to 'attach' to the process later.

Answer (score 0):

this may not be the best answer,  the only thing I need for debug is load .env in the first place, which heroku cli did that. I figured vscode allows set a envFile in the launch config.

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.go",
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
        }
    ]
}
```